# Signs to tell if Colab is executing code locally or on a machine somewhere else

Tags: resources, localhost, runtime, google-colaboratory, yolo

My gf is doing a project for college, trying to teach an AI to recognize tumors in lungs, using Google Colab and executing YOLO, that processes hundreds of images. We paid for Colab Pro to harness more resources at hand to do the job (which did speed things up(making me assume that it's run elsewhere)), but she is having trouble with the computer when the code is executing.

I am trying to narrow down why its CPU is maxed out from one of the running Chrome tabs, even tho the runtime is selected to run on Colab's servers, not locally. Her laptop has an i7 8565U, 8GB ram, and 2GB GPU. I assume it should use Colab's resources on google's machines, but it's doesn't seem to be so.

The data (images) is located on google drive and she shares it with Colab. I am wondering why the browser tab maxes out the CPU to the point that her computer becomes unresponsive. The only thing that I observed on that tab, seems like an AJAX where the browser tab displays what the google server machine is doing realtime. But I may be wrong. I tried to open the browser console but the laptop doesn't have resources to do it. Only way is to kill the process for that tab.

Just wondering if anyone has had this issue or similar, and could share a few steps how to diagnose this.

I may be missing something that I don't know about her project, but if you need me to check on something additional, I will dig in and will write back with results.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at the memory info and see if the total memory free looks like your laptop:

`!cat /proc/meminfo`

A Colab pro environment should have >20Gb of total memory.

Colab does not default to using local runtimes. Has she connected a local Jupyter/notebook runtime to the Colab notebook?

Try ending the browser process, reload the Colab notebook, and select 'Connect to hosted runtime' in the Connect dropdown menu (upper right hand corner, below the GDrive menu bar).